# Method belongs to the repository pattern or not?

Tags: java, structure, repository-pattern

Inside a concrete repository class, I have three methods:

1. Two methods that grab some data from a database. We can call them **A** and **B**.
2. The last method (named **C**) executes **A** and **B**, operates just few conditions on them and returns data.

Here is an example:

```
public Object A() { return data; }

public Object B() { return data; }

public Object C() {
    Object dataFromA = A();
    
    if (dataFromA == null && /* some conditions */)
        return B();

    return dataFromA;
}
```

When I look to the **C** method, it feels that it does not have to belong to the repository class. The only reason behind that is because the method **C** contains zero query and executes some internal methods.

What do you think about this "feeling" ? What could be a solution ?

Many thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to have only method that store and retrieve data from the database on repository class.

If I need to do some other operation i define a "Service" class that uses repository.

Whit this approch, if I need to write a new repository to fetch the data from a different database, i should only define the method that fetch the data (`methodA` and `methodB`), the logic of `methodC` remain the same.

```java
class Repository {

    Object methodA() {
        return data;
    }

    Object methodB() {
        return data;
    }
}

class Service {

    private Repository repo;

    Object getA() {
        return repo.methodA();
    }


    Object getB() {
        return repo.methodB();
    }

    Object methodC(){
        Object dataFromA = repo.methodA();
        
        if (dataFromA == null && /* some conditions */)
            return repo.methodB();

        return dataFromA;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In fact, that is exactly what I thought. But if I do that, it will create at least one new class : a service. For avoiding a strong coupling between my services, I need to create another class that will use this new service and the old ones. So, here is a new question: adding so much complexity is valuable when I can do that in just one class (in this case, the repository) ?